# react-router v6 still can't distinguish '/' and '/*'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I installed "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2".
And I heard that from v6, we don't need to use 'exact'

```
import React from "react";
import { HashRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import NotFound from "./screens/NotFound";

function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = false;
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={isLoggedIn ? <Home /> : <Login />} />
        <Route path="/agree" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

so I don't use 'exact' with path='/'.
but when I access through path '/agree' below, it still shows '/' website, which means it can't distinguish '/' and '/agree' even in v6.
And even if I use exact here, it doesn't work.
(probably because it's version 6? but why can't it distinguish them?)

please help me.

Comment: Can you check in `package.json` which version are you using?

Comment: @VeselinKontić

    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.1.2",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.19.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",

==> which means "6.0.2", isn't it?

Comment: Do you have that routes in NotFound component? I am using same staff in my project and it's working

Comment: Ah, you are using `HashRouter`. Try adding this to your URL `/#/about` or change to `BrowserRouter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `HashRouter`. Try adding this to your URL /#/about or change to `BrowserRouter`. The issue here is that you are entering `/about` which is not recognized by Router, cause it should be `/#/about` and that is the reason why it keeps showing you `/` page, which is in this case, considered 404 page.